# Clean way to reassign an object in es6 with conditionality

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ES6 and I can't find a cleaner way to make this code.

Can I get the child object if it exists or create it otherwise? To remove these ifs.

```
if (object?.tabs?.data) {
     object = {
       ...object,
       tabs: {
         ...object?.tabs,
         data: {
           ...object?.tabs?.data,
           id: newId,
         },
       },
     };
} else if (object?.tabs) {
     object = {
       ...object,
       tabs: {
         ...object?.tabs,
         data: {
           id: newId,
         },
       },
     };
} else {
    object = {
       ...object,
       tabs: {
         data: {
           id: newId,
         },
       },
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be a cleaner way:

```js
let newId = 1;

let object = {
 tabs: {
   data1: {
     id: 2
   }
 }
};

let o = (object = object ?? {});
for (let [k, v] of Object.entries({
    tabs: object?.tabs,
    data: object?.tabs?.data ?? {id: newId}
}))
  o = (o[k] = v ?? {});

console.log(object)
```